# Media query in CSS vs 'resize' listener in JS

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Is media query in CSS faster than the *resize* listener in Javascript?

$(window).on("resize", onResize);

```
function onResize(){
// code
}
```

Comment: Yes it is.......

Comment: CSS is always faster than JS